# div inline-block elements break when inserting another element inside

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

The first div breaks out of line. Why?

I know I can fix it with `vertical-align`, or `overflow`. but why this is happening from the beginning?

Link:
http://codepen.io/sergelerner/full/wKvsy

Comment: Add `vertical-align:top`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` for inline-block elements is `baseline`.

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box.
>
> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

When you add the `<p>` tag it becomes the baseline for the alignment. You can assign other value:

```
div {
 vertical-align:middle;
 /*or*/
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

The demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bcnDB